# How to access Doctrine defined methods after custom Repository is made?

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework2, doctrine

I am developing a site using ZF2 and Doctrine. The problem I am facing is I am using Doctrine predefined object methods like findAll(), findOneBy(), findBy() etc in my code. For some custom actions I have prepared a custom Repository for one of my entities. Now I can't access the predefined methods. I have already written code by using findAll() method. But after building a repository I can't simply access findAll() method. How can I both access my custom defined methods along with Doctrine defined methods?

For example:

I am using findOneBy() like this:

```
$udata = $this->em()->getRepository('Application\Entity\Usermain')->findOneBy(array('userEmail' => 'subh.laha@gmail.com'));
```

Now I have prepared UsermainRepository like below:

```
namespace Application\Entity\Repositories;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository;

class UsermainRepository extends EntityRepository
{   
    protected $sl;

    public function __construct($sl){

        $this->sl = $sl;    
    }

    public function customFind($arr)
    {
        $qb = $this->sl->createQueryBuilder();

        $whereStr = '';

        if(count($arr)){

            foreach($arr as $kvarr=>$varr){

                $whereStr .= "u.$kvarr = '".$varr."'";  
            }   
        }

        $qry = $qb->select('u')
                   ->from('Application\Entity\Usermain','u')
                   ->where($whereStr)
                   ->getQuery()
                   ->getResult(); 

        return $qry;
    }
}
```

Now I can access

```
$udata = $this->em()->getRepository('Application\Entity\Usermain')->customFind(array('userEmail' => 'subh.laha@gmail.com'));
```

But Not

```
$udata = $this->em()->getRepository('Application\Entity\Usermain')->findOneBy(array('userEmail' => 'subh.laha@gmail.com'));
```

Why? I have already written code by using doctrine defined methods. What can I do now?

Comment: Extending `EntityRepository` gives you access to pre-defined methods by default. What exactly you get as an error when you try to execute `findOneBy()`?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getUnitOfWork() on a non-object in /var/www/html/new_mpt_hk/mpt_hk/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php on line 194

Comment: @SubhasisLaha You have alot of issues here. Why have changed the method signature of the class? You *need* to have `__construct( Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em, Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata $class )` at a minimum. Also why are you injecting `$sl`? I'm assuming that it stand for `ServiceLocator`? There is not need for it and `$qb = $this->sl->createQueryBuilder();` is just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are getting this error because you have overridden the repository's constructor method but aren't calling the parent constructor so required parameters aren't being properly set.

Comment: I can't get your answer. How can I call the parent constructor and where? Can you give me any example?

Comment: I am badly stuck in it. Plz help.

Comment: @SubhasisLaha This answer is correct and is fairly basic OOP, you need to add `parent::__construct($entityManager, $classMetadata)` to the `__construct` method.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems exist in your approach;

- I think trying to access the service locator's itself in an entity repository is bad idea. You shouldn't need service container in repository level.
- The second detail is, when extending any class, you need to check out, read and respect the signature of the parent. In your case, you're overriding the parent's `__construct`. Calling `parent::__construct()` may seems like a solution but it's not. You'll soon realize that you also need a custom repository factory to pass additional arguments to constructor while keeping the current functionality. No way.
- This is more important than others: you believe that `$this->sl->createQueryBuilder()` returns query builder instance. Theoretically seems like working but `$this->sl` is not service locator, service locator doesn't knows anything about query builders, it's just `EntityManager` instance which passed to your constructor.

Try this:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Entity\Repositories;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UsermainRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function customFind($arr)
    {
        // Just pass an alias for your entity
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

        $whereStr = '';

        if (count($arr)) {
            foreach ($arr as $kvarr => $varr) {
                $whereStr .= "u.$kvarr = '".$varr."'";
            }
        }

        return $qb->where($whereStr)
                  ->getQuery()
                  ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Finally, in your `Application\Entity\Usermain` entity, you'll also need telling about your custom repository to doctrine since you don't want to use default `EntityRepository` :

```
namespace Application\Entity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Application\Entity\Repositories\UsermainRepository")
 */
class Usermain
{

}
```

Now in your controller (or service) level, you can test:

```
$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
$repo = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\Usermain');
// repo is a UsermainRepository instance
// this should work:
$udata = $repo->customFind(array('userEmail' => 'subh.laha@gmail.com'));
// this should also work
$udata = $repo->findOneBy(array('userEmail' => 'subh.laha@gmail.com'));
```

I strongly recommend carefully reading of [Working With Objects](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html) section of the documentation before diving into deeps.

Answer (score 2):

I think your code is not correct, You can use the below query instead of writing complex custom object.

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('U.id,U.name')  
                    ->from('Application\Entity\StudentClass', 'U')
                    ->where('U.pkStudentClass = :pkStudentClass')
                    ->setParameter('pkStudentClass', 1)
                    ->setMaxResults(20); 
                    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC') 
                    ->getQuery();

 $result = $query->getScalarResult();
```